# torch.cuda.OUtOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate xxx MiB

Tags: pytorch, gpu, out-of-memory

This is the error I got when I use pytorch to train my nerf model, which shows during the backward pass:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_dmsr.py", line 133, in <module>
    train()
  File "train_dmsr.py", line 64, in train
    total_loss.backward()
  File "/home/sue/anaconda3/envs/DM-NeRF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 489, in backward
    self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs=inputs
  File "/home/sue/anaconda3/envs/DM-NeRF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 199, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True, accumulate_grad=True)  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 288.00 MiB (GPU 0; 11.51 GiB total capacity; 9.94 GiB already allocated; 304.25 MiB free; 10.17 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I have tried to reduce the batchsize, but the error still exists, and it still shows the same amount of memory allocation (Tried to allocate 288.00 MiB).

I am not sure if it is because my GPU (11GB) is really out of memory or my GPU memory is not utilized.

I am also wondering if I should user a gpu server with larger memory or if there is any other solution to the Out of Memory Error?

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: yes, this pretty much means that GPU is out of memory.  `watch nvidia-smi` will show you the current GPU usage on linux. You can try reducing batch size further, or reduce the input size (e.g. lower resolution images)

Comment: It will always crash trying to allocate this amount of memory, if your batch size is too large and you use the same model (makes sense because Pytorch will allocate memory on the GPU in the same order again and crash at the same point). @asymptote I guess your comment should be the answer ;)